# SQL Default value current date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, timestamp

So I have this table created:

```
CREATE TABLE Hospital_MedicalRecord(
    recNo CHAR(5),
    patient CHAR(9),
    doctor CHAR(9),
    enteredOn DATE NOT NULL,
    diagnosis VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    treatment VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (recNo, patient),
    FOREIGN KEY (patient) REFERENCES Hospital_Patient(NINumber),
    FOREIGN KEY (doctor) REFERENCES Hospital_Doctor(NINumber)
);
```

I'm trying to have my table so the `enteredOn` column records date and time of when the medical record has been entered and I want to make the default value to the current date and time. I know I'm supposed to use current_timestamp but I don't know how to make it, everything that I've tried gives me errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
enteredOn DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Note: for this to work, your column must be declared as a `DATETIME` or a `TIMESTAMP` (not as a `DATE`).

If you do want a `DATE`, then you would need a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_Hospital_MedicalRecord_EnteredOn 
BEFORE INSERT ON Hospital_MedicalRecord
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.enteredOn= CURRENT_DATE();
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this example.

The format is

"Column name" "Type" "Qualifier, Null or Not Null" "Default" "Time"
Note that the datatype of the field must match with the method call. (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is a mysql method)

```
CREATE TABLE `asdf` (
    `Id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `RunDate` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```